# What is it missing/wrong with my new website not showing up?

Tags: php

Here's the steps I took:
1)
[image: Command Prompt]

2)
[image: path file]

3)
[image: error found]

For some reason I'm not able to figure out, this is not working. I'm a novice and I'm currently stuck here.
Any help will be much appreciated!
Thank you in advance,
Gabriel

Answer (score 2):

you should consider installing apache webserver and setup the host file in your pc
Apache :
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-install-Apache-HTTP-Server-on-Windows-Server

Set Hosts file in win :
https://docs.serverpress.com/article/176-windows-10-and-localhost-is-blank

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've been following this tutorial in youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OK_JCtrrv-c&t=7540s , and he didn't install anything more than what I did. Is there another way for having this working with the minimum changes in my pc?

Comment: you can install xamp:
https://www.wikihow.com/Install-XAMPP-for-Windows

Comment: this will insall all for you php, mysql and apache

Comment: While Apache is nice, this is a massively and unnecessarily complex solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new folder and then go to it in cmd using `cd` command. And move the file into it.
Then start the php server again and acces it using this link:
localhost:4000/site.php

Or install apache server as @mshahien said.
You can use xampp.

Comment: Hello Irfan, how exactly do I do the step you wrote 'go to it in cmd using cd command' ? I'm really beginner and I need a strong guidance to get out of this alive =)

Comment: Open that folder in file explorer. Then click on top where the link to the folder is and copy that link ( for example C:/Users/Irfan/Desktop/myphpapp) and execute this on cmd `cd C:/Users/Irfan/Desktop/myphpapp`

Answer (score 2):

You are running `php -S` in the wrong directory.

The `www` directory is inside a directory called `php` somewhere inside your One Drive directory, but you are running `php -S` from a directory called `i346241`.

The server started by `php -S` takes the **current** directory to be the root of the development server.